# Static or Pointer When "Returning" Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static

I'm attempting to load an array of size n (user input), with random values. I've read that you can not return an array in C, you must use a pointer (Which is quite confusing). However, I've read that if you are storing that array to a local variable in the returning function, a pointer will not work and a static array can be used (can that be returned in a function?). Also, I've read that you are supposed to call `free` after using the array is open the space back up? I must be using it wrong because it crashed. So I commented it out for now. Some clarification would be great.

Here's what I have so far. When printing, it's just printing what I'm assuming is just garbage.

```
int* prefixAverages1(int);

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int choice;
    int input;

    printf("What is the size of the array?:");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("Do you want to run prefixAverages 1 or 2?");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Beginning prefixAverages1\n");
            int *a = prefixAverages1(input);
            for (int i=0; i < input; i++) {
                printf("%d", &i);
                printf("%d \n", a[i]);
            }
            //free(a);
            break;
    }
}

int* prefixAverages1(int input) {
    int x[input];
    int *a = (int*)malloc(input);
    srand(time(NULL));  

    for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        int s = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int r = rand() % 100;
            x[j] = r;
            s = s + x[j];
        }
        a[i] = s / (i+1);
        printf("%d \n", a[i]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

I'm aware my syntax may be wonky. I haven't touched C in years, so let me know if my error is syntaxical.

edit: Values are printing as intended in the function. Added print statement in code for clairity

Comment: Why not just make an array in main() and send it to the function to be modified?

Comment: @AustinStephens I have thought of that, but I need the array to be passed back to the main eventually. Wouldn't that put me back into the same situation?

Comment: No, the array you send will be modified in main() as well; you don't have to return anything.

Comment: @AustinStephens I guess that's where the functionality of pointers come into play? That sounds like it would work, but my assignment explicitly asks for the array passed back to the main.

Comment: `printf("%d", &i);` == `printf("%d: ", i);`

Comment: @4386427 That solved my issue! Do you mind clarifying how that fixed it?

Comment: @InfoSecNick - see my ans below it has the explanation.. i is a local counter &i is the address of that variable you don't  want to print the address - but the variable - i

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` every time you call your `prefixAverages1()` function?  No - do not do that.  Call `srand()` fast enough that the return value of `time(NULL)` doesn't change between iterations and you'll get the same sequence of "random" numbers from your later calls to `rand()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm attempting to load an array of size n (user input), with random
>   values. I've read that you can not return an array in C, you must use
>   a pointer (Which is quite confusing).

Yes, the relationship between pointers and arrays and the surprisingly wide scope of things you cannot do with arrays themselves are common points of confusion.  To some extent it's a pedantic distinction.  Almost everything C allows you to do with an array, it makes you do via a pointer, but it automatically *converts* values of array type to appropriate pointers, so that those details are largely hidden.

But in some places it pokes out.  For example, there is no valid syntax that allows you even to try to declare a function that returns an array.

In other places it is actively misleading.  For example, you can declare a function that *appears* to accept an array as an argument, but the standard explicitly specifies that the argument is actually a corresponding pointer (and that's what naturally falls out when you call such a function anyway).  Specifically:

```
int foo(int x[3]);
```

is 100% equivalent to

```
int foo(int *x);
```

> However, I've read that if you
>   are storing that array to a local variable in the returning function,
>   a pointer will not work

That's not so much about arrays specifically, but rather about automatic variables in general.  These logically cease to exist when they go out of scope -- at the end of the innermost block in which they are declared -- so pointers to or into such objects are no longer valid once the function returns.  One way to obtain such a pointer value is for the function to return it.  That in itself is OK, but you cannot safely dereference such a pointer value.

> and a static array can be used (can that be
>   returned in a function?).

The lifetime of static variables of any type is the whole execution of the program.  Therefore, it is safe and can be meaningful to return a pointer (in)to a static variable from a function.  But although it can work to return a pointer to a static array from your function, you still cannot return such an array itself.

> Also, I've read that you are supposed to
>   call free after using the array is open the space back up?

You should free memory that you have allocated with one of the memory allocation functions (`malloc()` etc.), and no other.  But when you allocate memory inside a function, you can give the caller responsibility for freeing that memory by returning the pointer to it, among other ways.

In fact, most of what you demonstrate in your example code is fine in those regards.  However, you do make a key error that undermines your program.  Here:

> ```
>     int *a = (int*)malloc(input);
> ```

You allocate `input` *bytes* and store the pointer to them in `a`, but that is not enough storage for `input` objects of type `int`.  The size of an `int` varies from implementation to implementation, but the minimum size permitted by the standard is two bytes, in the most common size is four bytes.  To allocate space for `input` objects of type `int`, the basic idiom is

```
int *a = malloc(input * sizeof(int));
```

Personally, though, I prefer

```
int *a = malloc(input * sizeof(*a));
```

because then I get the correct size no matter what type the pointer's referenced type is, and even if I change it later.

The fact that you treated the allocated space as if it were larger than it really was likely explains much of your program's misbehavior, including the crash when you tried to free the allocated memory.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks for going through each of my questions and answering them individually.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `malloc` takes an inparam of no of bytes not absolute array size - so change this line:-

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(input);
```

to

```
int *a = malloc(input*sizeof(int));
```

Secondly, to debug incorrect values being printed put a print in your function `prefixAverages1` :-

```
...
...
a[i] = s / (i+1);
printf("%d \n", a[i]);
...
```

In main print, get rid of the first print.. this is probably making you think printing incorrect values.. The address of the local loop counter variable will look like garbage

```
printf("%d", &i);
```

OR if you wanted to track the indexes of the array elements as well modify it to :-

```
printf("%d", i);
```

You must introduce the `free` back to avoid leaking memory

And you should follow @AustinStephens's suggestion and avoid using a second function

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't exactly sure if I was using `malloc` correctly. Having changed that, I'm still getting incorrect values printed in the main.

Comment: The values are printing correctly in the function. It's solely when returning to the main.

Answer (score 0):

This works as far as having a function that loads an array with random values:

```
void randomValues(int arr[], int size);

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int input;
    int *array;

    printf("What is the size of the array?: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * input);

    randomValues(array, input);

    for(i = 0; i < input; ++i)
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);

    free(array);

    return 0;
}

void randomValues(int arr[], int size) {
    int i;
    int r;

    srand((int) time(0));

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        r = rand() % 100;
        arr[i] = r;
    }
}
```